# Run user application on a Switch/router?

Tags: networking, switch-statement, router, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

Can we run a packet sniffer/capture application on switch or router? My use case is to write a small software which will make certain decisions based on the content of the packet. Thanks. -Kedar

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [multilayer switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_switch), and probably it is layer 7 content routing you are after.

http://www.networkdictionary.com/networking/content.php

Comment: I don't know if this can be a solution, but what I am looking is to run a sniffer program on existing L2/L3 switch and read the packet content to take decision based on it. I wanted to know, if at all running a alien application program onto a L2/L3 switch is possible at first place.

Comment: @Kedar If you just want to snoop all traffic then [port mirroring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring) is what you need.